# php regex number and letters not allow just number

Tags: php

How can I get a string that contains a-zA-Z0-9-=&_. and not get a string 0-9

Example php:

```
$text1 = "2017";
$text2 ="php 2017";
```

Example function:

```
function allow($str) {
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_.]+/",$str)) {
    return $str;
}else{
    return false;
}
return $str;
}
```

like example

text 1 <- false.

text2 <- true.

Comment: how about `0.00` ?

Comment: what about 0.00 ? 0.00 what is ?

Comment: `0.00` is float number (if you didn't know)

Comment: ok thanks for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
function allow($str) {
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $str)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

What about if $str equals to ""? This function returns true for "".

Edit: [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) may be faster than regular expression.

```
function allow($str) {
    if (is_numeric($str)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```